# Vista condicional de tres variantes [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, vistas, views

> **Condiciones**

Ingreso - **suma**

Egreso - **resta**

se hace la operación **(Ingreso-Egreso)** entre los códigos que sean del **mismo** lugar.

> Tabla donde extraigo la información para crear la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Como quiero que quede la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Como queda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Codigo

Vista:

```
select 

/*Columna codigo*/
desglose_flujo_bobinas.Codigo AS Codigo,

/*Columna Cantidad en Lugar 1*/
IFNULL(((SELECT SUM(Peso) FROM desglose_flujo_bobinas where TIPO = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 1') -
             (SELECT SUM(Peso) FROM desglose_flujo_bobinas where TIPO = 'Egreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 1')),
(SELECT SUM(Peso) FROM desglose_flujo_bobinas where TIPO = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 1')) as 'Lugar 1',

/*Columna cantidad en Lugar 2*/
IFNULL(((select SUM(Peso) from desglose_flujo_bobinas where (Tipo = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 2')) -
             (select SUM(Peso) from desglose_flujo_bobinas where (Tipo = 'Egreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 2'))),
(select SUM(Peso) from desglose_flujo_bobinas where (Tipo = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 2'))) AS 'Lugar 2' 

from sige_gest_materiaprima.desglose_flujo_bobinas 

Group by Codigo
```

> Intente con

Validar con que código se estaba trabajo pero siendo la misma tabla caigo en una redundancia haciendo esta condición dentro del where (Codigo = Codigo).

->Devuelve exactamente la misma tabla

Pense en tomar como referencia el id de cada ítem pero no se me ocurre de que forma esto me puede ayudar.

> **PRIMERA ACTUALIZACION**

Probé concatenando los datos código con la ubicación dejando un  código parecido a este  `BOB-1Lugar1` hice una columna con el nombre de `codigoProducto` con esa información y la introduci en el where con esta condicion **`((SELECT CONCAT(Codigo, ubicacion) AS concatenado) = codigoProducto)`** esto me da este resultado, cabe resaltar que para conseguir al vista que obtengo abajo tambien le agregue al `GROUP BY` la columna codigoProducto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se asemeja mas a lo que necesito.

> **SEGUNDA ACTUALIZACION (Problema resuelto)**

La resolución la explico en la respuesta de la pregunta.

> Advertencia

Las tablas que use y el código que muestro es una adaptación de lo que tengo realmente, de echo las fotos están sacadas en una tabla de excel. Adapte todo para un mejor entendimiento y no marear con datos, columnas o código no relevante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema empece buscando un nuevo indice que tenga que ver con el código y a su vez con el tipo, este problema lo solucione en la **primer actualización** como bien lo muestro en la [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LLI6.png) de la tabla.

Ahora surgía un nuevo problema y era que aunque si bien las operaciones de sustracción las hacia correctamente no juntaba en una misma fila el código.

Si bien el resultado era el mismo no me terminaba de convencer la idea de duplicar datos y encontré la función **`GROUP_CONCAT`** que lo que hace es juntar los datos en una misma celda de las columnas que se le indique de esta manera `group_concat(col_1,col_2,...)` a su vez agrupo todo el select echo a los codigos para que se muestren todos los que encuentre (`GROUP BY codigo`).

Para concluir y dejar prolija la vista le asigno el tipo de dato que debe contener correctamente las columnas concatenadas haciendo uso de `unsigned` ya que si dejo que le asigne uno por defecto lo muestra como `STRING`.

Codigo final:

```
Select 
         tabla_datos_encontrados.codigoNo AS codigo, 
         CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(tabla_datos_encontrados.`Lugar 1` SEPARATOR ',') AS UNSIGNED)AS `Lugar 1`,
         CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(tabla_datos_encontrados.`Lugar 2` SEPARATOR ',') AS UNSIGNED) AS `Lugar 2`
        FROM
            (select 
            /*Columna codigo*/
            desglose_flujo_bobinas.bob_id as Flujo,
            (SELECT CONCAT(desglose_flujo_bobinas.codigo, desglose_flujo_bobinas.ubicacion_actual) AS codigoProd) AS codigoProducto,
            desglose_flujo_bobinas.Codigo AS Codigo
            /*Columna Cantidad en Lugar 1*/
            IFNULL(((SELECT SUM(Peso) FROM desglose_flujo_bobinas where TIPO = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 1') -
                         (SELECT SUM(Peso) FROM desglose_flujo_bobinas where TIPO = 'Egreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 1')),
            (SELECT SUM(Peso) FROM desglose_flujo_bobinas where TIPO = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 1')) as 'Lugar 1',
            /*Columna cantidad en Lugar 2*/
            IFNULL(((select SUM(Peso) from desglose_flujo_bobinas where (Tipo = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 2')) -
                         (select SUM(Peso) from desglose_flujo_bobinas where (Tipo = 'Egreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 2'))),
            (select SUM(Peso) from desglose_flujo_bobinas where (Tipo = 'Ingreso' AND ubicacion = 'Lugar 2'))) AS 'Lugar 2' 
            from sige_gest_materiaprima.desglose_flujo_bobinas 
        Group by Codigo, codigoProducto) as tablaDatosEncontrados
Group By Codigo
```

[**VISTA DEVUELTA**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmw75.png)